# ThreadLocal<T> constantly grows in size under certain conditions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, parallel.foreach

I'm running a simulation for certain number of iterations. After each iteration results are sent do the server and some time later server sends update data that is used in next iteration.

Code is (very roughly) looking like this:

```
for(var iteration=0;iteration<100;iteration++)
{
 Parallel.For(0,50,i=>DoExpensiveWork(i));
 SendResultsToServer(); //worker sends iteration results to server

 //server gathers results from all workers, 
 //calculates update, then sends it back to workers
 WaitForDataForNextIteration(); 
}
```

DoExpensiveWork is using ThreadLocal caches (mostly just big arrays that are reused every iteration to avoid GC work).

```
ThreadLocal<MyCache> _cache;

private void DoExpensiveWork(int i)
{
   var cache = _cache.Value;
   DoSomeWorkUsingCache(cache);
}
```

Here are problems I've encountered:

1. Over time `_cache` grows slowly (that is `_cache.Values.Count`) increases to value much higher than number of cores on my machine (I guess this means old threads are sometimes destroyed by `ThreadPool` and next iterations uses newly created threads leading to creation of additional entries in `_cache.Values`).
   This leads to a 'memory leak' as old caches are still kept in memory, while being inaccessible.
2. When server takes lot of time to send update then `_cache` grows on every iteration (on 32 core machine (2x16) `_cache.Values` grows like 32,64,96 etc - adding 32 new entries every iteration). This only happens when server takes ~20 seconds to send update (if it takes 15 seconds or less, this does not happen).
   Does this mean `ThreadPool` is tearing down threads when worker is stuck waiting for update?

How can I prevent this?
Setting min/max threads to 32 does not help

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(32,1000);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(32,1000);
```

What I want basically is to stop `ThreadLocal` cache creating new entries, so it does not grow above 32 in my case.

**Edit**: from MSDN: *When demand is low, the actual number of thread pool threads can fall below the minimum values.* This might explain why more and more `ThreadLocal` copies are created. Any workaround for this?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the same threads will be reused over and over again when using parallel.for (and why should they?), so maybe using ThreadLocal for cache is not the best idea in this case.

Comment: Why don't you use MemoryCache, it will remove cached item after certain time period if not accessed, this will avoid memory leak.